# Unsatisfied dependencies for type [***<T>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject

Tags: java, jboss, cdi, jboss-arquillian

When deploying to a jboss arquilian server, I've the following issue (that I don't seem to have when I deploy my local jboss server

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [CarPolicyServiceWithContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject com.athlon.thrift.web.utils.MSFOTContextUtils.carPolicyService]

### Injection

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MSFOTContextUtils {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Inject
    CarPolicyServiceWithContext carPolicyService;
```

### Provider

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceProvider {

    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance<CarPolicyServiceWithContext> carPolicyServices;



    private static final String COUNTRY = "NL";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceProvider.class);

     @Produces
    public CarPolicyServiceWithContext getCarPolicyService() {
        Instance<CarPolicyServiceWithContext> found = carPolicyServices.select(
                new CountryQualifier(COUNTRY));
        LOGGER.info("CarPolicyServiceWithContext loaded"+found.toString());
        return found.get();
    }

    public static class CountryQualifier
            extends AnnotationLiteral<Country>
            implements Country {
        private String value;

        public CountryQualifier(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String value() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

### Bean

```
@Country("NL")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CarPolicyNetherlandsService implements CarPolicyServiceWithContext<MSFOTContext> {
```

I added some logging in the provider, but I don't see it printed in the arquillian jboss logs...

Thanks !

Comment: Did you tried to create a war file and deployed as well? It seems to me more a "problem" on CDI configuration rather than an arquillian problem.

Comment: CDI is very type safe, you have a generic in  your interface.  I'm not sure what relevancy it has to your use cases,but this means you have to reference it as `CarPolicyServiceWithContext< MSFOTContext>`

Comment: Are you sure, that Provider is in your Arquillian Deployments? Is it in your regular WAR, or did you add this version to support tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the @Deployment archive, for some reason, the ServiceProvider class above was not added in the archive.